# localhost | wrong path to file | JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, localhost

A couple days ago I started learning Node JS and after couple hours I opened my localhost and it didn't have any css or JS, because of that the wrong path to files that I wrote. Could someone tell me what exactly I need to write in path, so the localhost won't give error like `GET http://localhost:3000/index.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)`

```js
// MY NODE JS CODE:
const express = require('express')
const app = express();
const http = require('http').Server(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
})

app.use('/static', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    console.log('connected');
    socket.on('disconnect', function() {
        console.log('disconnected');
    });
});

http.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log('listening on localhost:3000');
});
```

```html
<!-- MY INDEX HTML CODE: -->
<link href="styles.css"> <!-- 1 link -->
<script src="index.js"></script> <!-- 2 link -->

<div id="something"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
})

app.use('/static', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

into

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

Comment: What exactly should I write for the code to work?

Comment: I have edited the comment, please check again

Comment: Now I have an error `Cannot GET /` on the main page and `GET http://localhost:3000/ 404 (Not Found)` in console

Comment: Idk, I have tested it and it worked fine hmm?
https://prnt.sc/1cnvikw